# SelectedIndices always gives -1 value winforms

Tags: winforms, listview, ironpython

I am trying to create a form in winforms with a listview in it. I want to set it up so as when I select a row and press a button, the index of that row is returned.

The problem is whenever I select a row, the form returns the ListViewItem correctly via *(mylistView.SelectedItems)*. However, it always returns index value of (-1) as if nothing is selected via *(mylistView.SelectedIndices)*. Also *(mylistView.SelectedItems.Count)* returns 0.

So I have 2 columns and an input list (inputlist) which looks like [[2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5],...] My code looks like this:

```
for index, c in enumerate (self.inputlist):
        self.item = ListViewItem()
        self.item.Text = str (self.inputlist[index][0])
        self.item.SubItems.Add(str(self.inputlist[index][1]))
        self._listView1.Items.Add(self.item)
self.items = self._listView1.SelectedItems
self.index = self._listView1.SelectedIndices
self.count = self._listView1.SelectedItems.Count
```

Comment: Your code return 0 because you have not selected anything you just populated values in the listView

Comment: I then initialize the form and select an item from the list ( I also append the self.items, self.index, self.count to an output list) Only "self.items" returns the selected item.

Comment: Add part where you add items and select them

Comment: I select the items in the winform window when I run the code. and the output is like
outputlist.append([self.items, self.index, self.count]) , whereby only self.items seems to retain the value of the selected item.
I managed to make a workaround where I perform some string operations on self.items to get its index from the original list (self.inputlist) and it worked for the time being for the deadline but I would really like to know what is wrong.